# image height to full div height when container cant be changed

Tags: html, css, image, height

I have a situation were I cannot alter the main container and also implement `body,html` height and margin.

I am wanting to set the image via CSS and I am wanting the DIV to be the full height and width of the image.

What is the best way to achieve this most of the things I have found on google uses a `div` then a `img` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a background image in the div and set width/height to the dimensions of the image.

It's also easy to scale the image using background-size values of cover or contain.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

```
<div style="background-image:url('image.jpg'); width:100px; height:100px;"></div>
```

Or use the background-size dimensions

```
<div style="background-image:url('image.jpg'); background-size:100px 100px; width:..; height:..;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a js fiddle plz